# making convolution in matlab manualy

Tags: matlab-figure

I want to make convolution image processing in matlab without to use (conv2) command
I want to use (.^) command with 2 for loop
I make this code to make LoG 5x5 filter
but it not work in this line (I(r,c) =sum(sum( Mask.* I( (r-2):(c-2), (r+2):(c+2) ) ));)

```
clc
clear;
Img = imread ('11.jpg');                                               %reading Image
for x = 1:size(Img,1)                                                  % converting to Gray 
    for y =1:size(Img,2)
        G (x,y)= (Img(x,y,1)*0.3 + Img(x,y,2)*0.59 + Img(x,y,1)* 0.11);
    end
end
Mask = [0,0,-1,0,0;0,-1,-2,-1,0;-1,-2,16,-2,-1;0,-1,-2,-1,0;0,0,-1,0,0]; % the mask
I=double(G);Mask=double(Mask);
% I=conv2(G,Mask);                                                      % masking quickly
for r = 3: size(I,1)-2                                                  %masking manualy
   for c = 3: size(I,2)-2
      I(r,c) =sum(sum( Mask.* I( (r-2):(c-2), (r+2):(c+2) ) ));
   end
end
imshow(Img);title('Orginal Image');
figure,imshow(G);title('Gray Image');
figure,imshow(uint8(I));title('Proccessed Image');
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug is a good way to solve some problems.

When c = 4, r = 3(The second loop in "for c = 3: size(I,2)-2")

I( (r-2):(c-2), (r+2):(c+2) ) is a 2 * 2 Matrix,

and Mask is a 5*5 Matrix.

So the error message is "Matrix dimensions must be consistent".